# Add 1 Page to each PDF in folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I have a folder with 100s of PDF versions of PPT presentations.  I also have a one page PDF file that I want to add to the beginning of each PDF file.  Is there a way I can do this with PHP?  Could I maybe use the Zend Framework?

Comment: Does it have to be PHP based? There is a number of good command-line PDF merge tools around.

Comment: Brian@ I would look at the two libraries I mentioned first. PHP is less bumpy and safier when you go with something thats more native. And for what you need, a command line tool would be more work then it's worth (the ol' killing a fly with a sledgehammer situation).

Comment: I guess I should read before I speak. When I was looking for a form filler, I could have sworn that both of the libraries I mentioned did everything BUT that. But it seems that I was quite wrong. If you can use command-line and have jcc installed on your server, just use pdftk. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly can be done by Zend_Framework!

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($fileName);
$frontPdf = Zend_Pdf::load('/path/to/template.pdf');

$frontPage = $frontPdf->pages[0];

//prepend our template front page to PDF
array_unshift($pdf->pages, $frontPage);

//update original document
$pdf->save($fileName, true);
```

I haven't tested the code here but we have an application working on the same principle.

Check the [documentation for pages within Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.pages.html) if you have any problems.

Comment: Is there a way to determine if the front page has already been added?  i.e. is there a way to see if the current first page is identical to the single page file?

Comment: I've never tried to do that - it may be possible to compare the protected $_contents of a page if you make a subclass. Ideally you would convert all docs at one point and just know that they've been processed, but I can appreciate that might not always be possible.